# Ionic 2 : Underline title on selected tab

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, ionic2

I use ion-tabs on my application. When user touch the tab the title become underline but I don't want this :

[image]

I don't understand why, I don't know how to change it.

I just want something like this :

[image]

And I have it if I touch elsewhere.

There is my code :

```
<ion-tabs tabsHighlight="false">
  <ion-tab [root]="HomePage" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
           tabIcon="checkbox"
           tabTitle="A FAIRE"
           tabBadge="2"
           tabBadgeStyle="notif">
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="ToComePage"
           tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
           tabIcon="time" tabTitle="A VENIR"
           tabBadge="1"
           tabBadgeStyle="notif">
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="HistoricPage"
           tabsHideOnSubPages="true"
           tabIcon="book"
           tabTitle="HISTORIQUE">
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Someone have an idea to fix it ?

Comment: I see you already use tabsHighlight=false, it worked for me but I have only text-tabs no icons =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this CSS

**EDIT**

```
 .tab-button:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: In my variables.scss ? I try this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Change `.parentClass ion-tab:hover` to `.tab-button:hover` and try again?

Comment: It works ! You can update your answer ! :D Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.tab-item:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```